# Fix FxCop CA1305 for string interpolation via Visual Studio "Search and Replace"

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

This [link](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2015/09/c-6-interpolated-strings-and-code.html) describes how to fix the FxCop warning `CA1305` for string interpolation cases. You have to replace `$"somestring"` with `Invariant($"somestring")`, and also include the namespace as static.

I'm actually struggling how to replace all this occurrences via Visual Studios `Search and Replace` feature. Can someone give a hint how to replace this occurrences via a Regex in Visual Studio?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say you are trying. Please share the best attempt and describe what it matches well, what doesn't it match, i.e. explain the expected behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a capture group like:

```
(\$".*")
```

And than reference to the via:

```
Invariant($1)
```

[image]